# regex to detect leading zeros and check the lenght from 0 to 12 digits

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I have a javascript function that checks for signed integer with 0 to 12 length, i also want to see if there are any leading 0's  like 0012 should return false.

```
function sInteger0to12(str) {
    str = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    return /^[-+]?\d{0,12}$/.test(str);
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a list of example outputs?

Comment: A signed integer of 0 length? So you should accept the empty string? Should you also accept the strings '-' or '+'?

Comment: +12313241, -12312312 , 1230
but not 
+00123 or -00123 or -021 or - or +

Comment: Shah: what about the empty string? According to your expression, that should be accepted, but this seems strange to me. Do you really want to accept the empty string?

Comment: What about +0 and -0. Should these both be allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that the following should match:

```
1
+1
-1
0
-123456789012
<empty>
```

And these should fail:

```
-
+
01
-01
1234567890123
00
+0
-0
```

If you disagree with my decisions above, please let me know and I will try to fix the regex.

Here's a regex you can use:

```
/^([-+]?[1-9]\d{,11}|0)?$/
```

Comment: This matches the empty string.

Comment: I also feel that allowing the empty string is a bit off. Just pointing out that you'd changed it in the description but not edited the regex accordingly.

Comment: Anon: now he wants to match the empty string! So I changed it back.. this is going to get confusing soon. I need to check the +0 and -0...

Comment: It's always difficult to answer these questions where the OP is has extremely precise ideas about how it should work, but the actually requirements are not specified in the question... only some vague description, and then to get the exact information you have to ask repeatedly for each and every test case what the required output is.... :(

Comment: This is the real reason that programming is hard - you can never get a clear spec from the start.

Comment: I'm tired of waiting for the answer about the +0 and -0. The fix is to add [+-]? before the zero if +0 and -0 are both wanted as matches.

Comment: no worries guys i can take it from here. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
 /^[-+]?[1-9]\d{0,11}$/
```

You'll need to check for `'0'` separately.

Comment: I took the liberty to change `112` to `11`.

Comment: +12313241, -12312312 , 1230 but not +00123 or -00123 or -021 or - or + –

Comment: If you really wanted to not have to check 0 separately ... `/^[-+]?([1-9]\d{0,11}|0)$/`

Answer (score 0):

You need to cover three cases

1. an empty string
2. a single 0
3. a no zero padded 1 to 12 digit number

these cases equate to

1. ^$
2. ^0$
3. ^[+-]?[1-9]\d{0,11}$

which adds up to

```
^()|(0)|([+-]?[1-9]\d{0,11})$
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
/(^0$)|(^[+-]?[1-9]\d{0,11}$)/
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of why you think this helps.